# Docker failed building Rust Image on Apple M1

Tags: linux, docker, rust, dockerfile, apple-m1

I'm trying to build a docker image on a MacBookPro M1, but it fails everytime.
The image is based on the official Rust image and the goal is to build it, so I can run it on my server, which is an Ubuntu.

The Dockerfile:

```
FROM rust:1.59 as builder
WORKDIR /usr/src/auth-server

COPY . .
RUN cargo install --path .

FROM debian:buster-slim
WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY ./common/*.sh ./
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
RUN chmod +x ./wait-for-it.sh ./wait-for-mysql.sh
COPY --from=builder /usr/local/cargo/bin/auth-server /usr/local/bin/auth-server

ENTRYPOINT [ "./wait-for-mysql.sh" ]
CMD ["auth-server"]
```

The build command:

```
docker build auth-server -t ta_auth_server:latest --platform linux/x86_64
```

Cargo.toml:

```
[package]
name = "auth-server"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2018"

[dependencies]
actix-web          = "3.3.2"   # HTTP Server
actix-cors         = "0.5.4"   # HTTP Server CORS middleware
futures            = "0.3"     # Async Helpers
r2d2               = "0.8"     # SQL Connection Pool
jsonwebtoken       = "7.2.0"   # Authentication
ring               = "0.16.20" # Crypto
tracing            = "0.1.28"  # Logging
tracing-subscriber = "0.3"
toml               = "0.5.8"   # TOML Config
rust-argon2        = "1.0"   # Secure Password Hasher
rand               = "0.8"     # Secure Random
base64             = "0.13"    # Base 64 Encoder/Decoder
serde_json         = "1.0"     # Serial JSON

[dependencies.diesel]          # Database client
git = "https://github.com/diesel-rs/diesel"
rev = "c06aa5ed88d2670d6e0d68124a6b426f22ab5079" # 2.0.0
#version            = "1.4.8"
features = ["mysql", "chrono", "serde_json", "r2d2"]

[dependencies.serde]           # Serial
version = "1.0.130"
features = ["derive"]

[dependencies.chrono]          # UTC Time
version = "0.4"
features = ["serde"]

[dependencies.smallvec]        # Performat Vec
version = "1.6.1"
features = ["serde"]
```

The build output:

```
#1 [internal] load build definition from Dockerfile
#1 sha256:6c3945f4e6a239ff4dfe37b0796b3f999128b83fc3b215f2886dbf03e20e2536
#1 transferring dockerfile: 37B 0.0s done
#1 DONE 0.0s

#2 [internal] load .dockerignore
#2 sha256:1caa71207477144555998e3d3648069c238cfe141a13e87658cf83476d0b1d8a
#2 transferring context: 34B done
#2 DONE 0.0s

#4 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/rust:1.59
#4 sha256:c2b8f0eec313f72bc7d2c52435b15771ad2e6be09ae47d3c2e0efe02283ca8fc
#4 DONE 1.0s

#3 [internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/debian:buster-slim
#3 sha256:9eff6dca560982b2e63ff856e62cbe563510aefae21ffbf5035ede9ce6b0ad90
#3 DONE 1.6s

#5 [stage-1 1/6] FROM docker.io/library/debian:buster-slim@sha256:fac2ae50be3f4e0901582e5c0ef00d06b1f599315a2077ab5b8ea7e304ddbee4
#5 sha256:b57f8a54c82b181481466e63f43b4243eb95be6efaf5095d58ab11aefda979cc
#5 DONE 0.0s

#11 [builder 1/4] FROM docker.io/library/rust:1.59@sha256:7c0ea3ee40fc4f12a43de1b9967bc5df1337bf469253c322a98952079493448b
#11 sha256:a97310b0b2f637acd07ecedbd207a8c9f5c5fa98a5eda098f441030d1a2a3446
#11 DONE 0.0s

#7 [internal] load build context
#7 sha256:d9a90ea0dce73a2dd2991c2f59f285a419d35192dba66861392823f655cc7cfb
#7 transferring context: 760B done
#7 DONE 0.0s

#12 [builder 2/4] WORKDIR /usr/src/auth-server
#12 sha256:1d5c76722440262694bbeca90924483cc0feb891d9d59c3c5721b6b36b982b45
#12 CACHED

#9 [stage-1 4/6] RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y default-mysql-client && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
#9 sha256:62d2853cc00902fa4338d0f296ef4921b4d2d7a356f805779e68bfcbbb79c89e
#9 CACHED

#6 [stage-1 2/6] WORKDIR /usr/app
#6 sha256:b743b8f0c2aa26b2111dd0c1092ffa4b9f29629158ed2b6e5a56c712ae2af991
#6 CACHED

#8 [stage-1 3/6] COPY ./common/*.sh ./
#8 sha256:2f9508b5b0a03c2c64132822174b78677547b0524012d1e45f351b2cd040a70f
#8 CACHED

#10 [stage-1 5/6] RUN chmod +x ./wait-for-it.sh ./wait-for-mysql.sh
#10 sha256:2dfd8162b6cefda29f9e9019846fab392ffa07eeafdcf546962645fc2edad05a
#10 CACHED

#13 [builder 3/4] COPY . .
#13 sha256:9455a328aff0e42274d134c73d12d65ee90822ff0e2ba4151132e1753f011c3f
#13 CACHED

#14 [builder 4/4] RUN cargo install --path .
#14 sha256:51e2661717978ed5209e1835d5f13955acd9066df77b3f2db3cd635ec199c2f2
#14 2.737   Installing auth-server v0.1.0 (/usr/src/auth-server)
#14 6.591     Updating crates.io index
#14 57.11 Killed
#14 ERROR: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cargo install --path .]: exit code: 137
------
 > [builder 4/4] RUN cargo install --path .:
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c cargo install --path .]: exit code: 137
```

I think it run out of memory but I have no idea why and how to solve it.
Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe you can post your `Cargo.toml` ?

Comment: @Philippe Yep is posted

Comment: I got this error `error: failed to parse manifest at '/usr/src/auth-server/Cargo.toml'`

Comment: @Philippe Okay thats strange. I have never had this error before

Comment: Have you tried latest `rust` version, to see if it works ?

Comment: @Philippe Yes but is also not working

Answer (score 0):

you should use a Rust image built for ARM architecture. You can use the official Rust image for ARM architecture by changing the base image in your Dockerfile to:

```
FROM rust:1.59-slim-buster as builder
```

This image is built for the ARM architecture, which is compatible with the M1 chip.

Once you've made this change, you can try building the image again using the same command:

```
docker build auth-server -t ta_auth_server:latest --platform linux/x86_64
```

Comment: I've tried it this way, but the error remains the same